# Panda Sum value is not correct

Tags: pandas

wondering if you can point me to what i'm doing wrong.

i have a panda structure :

```
>>> df_merged.tail(1)
    non_negative_derivative_x                  time non_negative_derivative_y non_negative_derivative_x non_negative_derivative_y
287              1.637120e+09  2018-03-31T13:15:00Z                  10574.72               5.19642e+09               5.78985e+09
```

i'm trying to get the sum of all fields except time with

df_merged['bps']=df_merged.drop('time', axis=1).sum(axis=1)

```
df_merged.tail(1)
    non_negative_derivative_x                  time non_negative_derivative_y non_negative_derivative_x non_negative_derivative_y           bps
287              1.637120e+09  2018-03-31T13:15:00Z                  10574.72               5.19642e+09               5.78985e+09  1.637130e+09
```

The 'bps' value is not the sum..

Update

this was because i had NA values. I was doing a merge with

df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['time'],how='outer'), df_variable).fillna('NA') and some rows had NA.

When i do df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['time'],how='outer'), df_variable).fillna(0)

```
df_merged.tail(1)
    non_negative_derivative_x                  time non_negative_derivative_y non_negative_derivative_x non_negative_derivative_y
287              1.637120e+09  2018-03-31T13:15:00Z                  10574.72               5.19642e+09               5.78985e+09

    df_merged['bps']=df_merged.drop('time', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

df_merged.tail(1)

```
 non_negative_derivative_x                  time  non_negative_derivative_y  non_negative_derivative_x  non_negative_derivative_y           bps
287               1.637120e+09  2018-03-31T13:15:00Z                   10574.72               5.196423e+09               5.789848e+09  1.262340e+10
```

Comment: Your code is correct  , i have tested it on Python 3.6 the output values is : `0  1.263001e+10`  And Excel Also seems to give same output.

Comment: Should be the value of each non_negative_derivative_

Comment: I would guess you changed the values between creating your first df and summing. Because I also calculated the same resulat as @RehanAzher

Comment: No. but it think , it just calculates first two values. 1.637120e+09 + 10574.72 = 1.637130e+09 and don't understand why.

Answer (score -1):

this was because i had NA values. I was doing a merge with

See update on the question